# Uploading data using C# console application

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a C# console application that uploads data into SQL Server database after doing a bit of calculation which is done using various C# functions. Now the problem is it is taking almost 1 sec to calculate and upload one line of data and I have to upload 50,000 lines of data in the same way.

Please suggest me a way to solve this problem.

P.S. : I am using stringbuilder to compose separate insert statements and upload in bulk. This process is taking only 1 min.

---

Inserting or updating to database is hardly taking any time as I have mentioned in my question. Calculation is taking most of the time. I am attaching the code sample of a function below:

```
public void EsNoMinLim()

{
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds = getDataSet("select aa.Country, aa.Serial_No from UEM_Data aa inner join (select distinct " +
            "IId, Country from UEM_Data where Active_Status is null) bb on aa.iid = bb.iid where aa.Serial_No <> '0'").Copy();

        execDML("Delete from ProMonSys_Grading");

        StringBuilder strCmd = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            SiteCode = dRow["Country"].ToString();
            Serial_No = dRow["Serial_No"].ToString();

            ds_sub = new DataSet();
            ds_sub = getDataSet("select EsNo_Abs_Limit from EsNo_Absolute_Limit where Fec_Coding_Rate in "+
                "(select MODCOD from FEC_Master where NMS_Value in (select Top 1 FEC_Rate from "+
                "DNCC_Billing_Day where Serial_No = '" + Serial_No + "' and [Date] = (select max([Date]) "+
                "from DNCC_Billing_Day where Serial_No = '" + Serial_No + "')))").Copy();

            if (ds_sub.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && Convert.ToString(ds_sub.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]) != "")
            {
                Min_EsNo = Convert.ToString(ds_sub.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
            }
            else
            {
                Min_EsNo = "a";
            }

            if (Min_EsNo != "a")
            {
                ds_sub = new DataSet();
                ds_sub = getDataSet("select Top 1 modal_Avg_EsNo from DNCC_Billing_Day where " +
                    "Serial_No = '" + Serial_No + "' and [Date] = (select max([Date]) from DNCC_Billing_Day " +
                    "where Serial_No = '" + Serial_No + "')").Copy();

                if (ds_sub.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && Convert.ToString(ds_sub.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]) != "")
                {
                    Avg_EsNo = Convert.ToString(ds_sub.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Avg_EsNo = "-1";
                }

                ds_sub = new DataSet();
                ds_sub = getDataSet("select Top 1 Transmit_Power from ProMonSys_Threshold where Serial_No = '" + Serial_No + "'").Copy();

                if (ds_sub.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && Convert.ToString(ds_sub.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]) != "")
                {
                    Threshold_EsNo = Convert.ToString(ds_sub.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Threshold_EsNo = "-1";
                }

                getGrade = EsNoSQFGrading(Min_EsNo, Avg_EsNo, Threshold_EsNo);

                strCmd.Append("insert into ProMonSys_Grading(SiteCode, Serial_No, EsNo_Grade) " +
                            "values('" + SiteCode + "','" + Serial_No + "','" + getGrade + "')");
            }
        }

        execDML_StringBuilder(strCmd);
    }
```

Comment: not enough info to answer question.

Comment: How large is each chunk of data, on average?

Comment: use a profiler to see wich part of your application is consuming  most of the time and optimize

Comment: Show us the code. Also: what happens if you write the results to a local file instead of calling `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: What is the calculation you are doing? Is it even remotely possible that the calculation is taking time?

Answer (score 0):

Find out, what part of the process is the expensive one. Use StopWatch to check how long loading, calculating and saving takes separately. Then you which part to improve (and can tell us).